# Embed CSS in Shiny App

Tags: html, css, r, shiny

I am working to embed a stylized ordered list into the front page of my shiny app using CSS. The specific problem I am experiencing is everything on my landing page (overview tab) is blank until I navigate away from the "overview" page and then return back to it. When I return back to the "overview" tab, everything appears on the page as intended.

If I comment out the tags() argument at the top, then the sidebar and other text appears, but not the ordered list, as expected. So, perhaps this is a hint of where the problem lies, but I cannot find a solution and could use support.

Can anyone find a way to get the code to work such that when the shiny app launches, the overview page is immediately visible with the sidebar page text as well as the ordered list?

I have my directory structure organized as follows:

## Directory structure

```
--myApp' folder holding ui.r and server.r
        
-- 'HTML' folder as subdirectory in 'myApp' holding the html file below called 'methods.html'

--'www' folder as subdirectory in 'myApp' holding the file called 'list.css'
```

I have provided all code below to reproduce a problem I am experiencing with my shiny app.Thank you for any support offered.

## ui.R

```
library(markdown)
shinyUI(navbarPage("Toolbar",
 tags$head(
    tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", type = "text/css", href = "list.css")
  ),
tabPanel("Overview",
titlePanel("Some Text"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      h2("Purpose of this web application"),
      p("Text to go here"),
      br(),
      br()
    ),
    mainPanel(
        includeHTML("HTML/methods.html")
   )
  )
), # end tabpanel
  tabPanel("Do Stuff Tab 1",
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel( 
    fileInput('Rfile1', 'Read in File 1', accept=c('.RData', '.Rda')),
    fileInput('Rfile2', 'Read in File 2', accept=c('.RData', '.Rda'))
    ), # end sidebar
        mainPanel(
        h1('Some Report')
      )
    )
  ) # end tabpanel 
)) # end program
```

## server.r

```
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
File <- reactive({
infile <- input$school
if (is.null(infile)) return(NULL)      
read.csv(infile$datapath, header=input$headerForPE, sep=input$sepForPE, quote=input$quoteForPE, 
stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
})
}) # end Program
```

## HTML (methods.html)

```
<ol class="circle-list">
<li>
<h2>Foo 1</h2>
<p>This will have text</p>
</li>
<li>
<h2>Foo 2</h2>
<p>Blah Blah</p>
</li>
</ol>
```

## CSS (list.css)

```
<style>
body{
margin: 40px auto;
width: 500px;
}
ol{
counter-reset: li;
list-style: none;
*list-style: decimal;
font: 15px 'trebuchet MS', 'lucida sans';
padding: 0;
margin-bottom: 4em;
text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.5);
}
ol ol{
margin: 0 0 0 2em;
}
.circle-list li{
padding: 2.5em;
border-bottom: 1px dashed #ccc;
}
.circle-list h2{
position: relative;
margin: 0;
}
.circle-list p{
margin: 0;
}
.circle-list h2:before{
content: counter(li);
counter-increment: li;
position: absolute;    
z-index: -1;
left: -1.3em;
top: -.8em;
background: #f5f5f5;
height: 1.5em;
width: 1.5em;
border: .1em solid rgba(0,0,0,.05);
text-align: center;
font: italic bold 1em/1.5em Georgia, Serif;
color: #ccc;
-moz-border-radius: 1.5em;
-webkit-border-radius: 1.5em;
border-radius: 1.5em;
-webkit-transition: all .2s ease-out;
-moz-transition: all .2s ease-out;
-ms-transition: all .2s ease-out;
-o-transition: all .2s ease-out;
transition: all .2s ease-out;    
}
.circle-list li:hover h2:before{
background-color: #ffd797;
border-color: rgba(0,0,0,.08);
border-width: .2em;
color: #444;
-webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
-moz-transform: scale(1.5);
-ms-transform: scale(1.5);
-o-transform: scale(1.5);
transform: scale(1.5);
}
</style>
```

Comment: Just to close the loop here, I was able to solve my problem by putting the tags() function into the mainPanel() of the first tab. This now works as expected.

Comment: It might be helpful to others if you post the code to your solution.